# Let $p$ be a prime. Show that there exists a Complete System of Residues modulo $p,$ $\{q_1, q_2, ..., q_p \}$, where $q_i$ are prime numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I know this is true by *Dirichlet's Prime Number Theorem*, but I'm struggling to come up with a more elementary proof of this fact.
So far, the book has showed up to *Euler-Fermat's Theorem* and *Wilson's Theorem*, so I imagine I should be able to do it using only the tools, but couldn't figure out how.

Comment: But this is equivalent to Dirichlet's Theorem.  Well, at least the part that asserts the existence of primes in (suitable) arithmetic progressions (not the density bits).

Comment: I have seen this question asked like 4 times this week. Why do people assume this is possible?

Comment: Well, this is a proposed exercise in a fairly simple undergrad book on Number Theory that is really famous here in Brazil. Maybe more people got stuck at it, I don't know...

Comment: As an (elementary) exercise you might want to try to prove that the existence of at least  one prime in  prime in all good progressions implies the existence of infinitely many.  Here, of course, a "good" progression is one for which the period is relative prime to any given term.

Comment: I think I see how that would be the case but, since it is an exercise on an undergrad book, I thought there could possibly be a "tricky way" of proving such statement.

Comment: I find it hard to believe the text expects its readers to prove existence.  Is it possible that they simply wanted you to argue that this followed from Dirichlet?  Was, for example, Dirchlet quoted earlier in that chapter?

Comment: That's the thing: It wasn't cited *at all*. Nowhere in the book, even further on, it cites *Dirichlet's*. The furthest it goes is proving, at the appendix,*Bertrand's Postulate*.

Comment: The question itself asks if such Complete System is possible, without ever mentioning anything Dirichlet-related, so I figured I needed to show it, somehow.

Comment: This question is answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1305721/48606

Comment: @MatheusNasi is this the exact statement of the problem?  There would be much easier answers if e.g. they gave a particular (small) value of $p$, or required that none of the $q_i$ is equal to $p$.  But I agree with everyone else that the problem as stated is no easier than Dirichlet.

Comment: @RaviFernando Quoting the question: " Given a prime *p*, is it always possible to find a complete system of residues modulo *p* with only prime elements? Justify. "

Comment: What’s the book? Are you sure you didn’t just miss it being mentioned? If you only looked at the index, sometimes those aren’t very great.

Comment: @TokenToucan It's only avaliable in portuguese, it's called "Introdução à Teoria dos Números"(Introduction to Number Theory), by José Plínio, and I'm sure I didn't miss it, because I have read everything so far, and also other students from my class were having the same issue with this specific exercise.